# REGEXP_REPLACE how to using multiple replacement_string

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

how to multiple replacement string using `regexp_replace` in oracle?

```
formula = 1*3

formula detail (1->value1, 2->value3, 3->value3)
```

I want the result

```
formula = value1*value3
```

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far

Comment: Look into [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4176071) and [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/856316).

Comment: I've try using regexp_substr and level. but its not complete, its just get the arithmetic operator

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what this:

```
formula = 1*3

formula detail (1->value1, 2->value3, 3->value3)
```

actually represents. What is the first row? Is it a string, stored in some table? Is it a string stored in a variable? Is it the *complete* string, or is the *string* just `1*3` (without `formula =`)?

What is the second row? The same doubts as for the first one.

---

Anyway: if we pretend that the first row represents a string, while the second represents your wish and not some code, then nested `REPLACE` (i.e. no regular expressions at all) does the job:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_rep
  2    (par_1 in varchar2, par_2 in varchar2, par_3 in varchar2)
  3  return varchar2
  4  is
  5    l_str varchar2(200) := 'formula = 1*3';
  6  begin
  7    l_str := replace(replace(replace(l_str, '1', par_1),
  8                                            '2', par_2),
  9                                            '3', par_3);
 10    return l_str;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_rep('value1', null, 'value3') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
formula = value1*value3

SQL>
```

Comment: formula is name field column and the value is formula for counting something. and the value is dynamic value.

Comment: I've try using replace, but its static

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you are saying. If possible, edit the initial message you posted, explain the problem in more details, provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, attach a screenshot ... whatever you think might be useful to help us help you.